# Не работает ActiveSheet.UsedRange в Excel

Tags: excel, office

*Привет !*

Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке сбросить `last cell` в `Excel`.
Я *пробовал* сделать [такую же](http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/resetting-the-last-cell-in-an-excel-worksheet) имитацию.

- Создал пустую таблицу
- Добавил значение в `A10` (к примеру)
- Перешел при помощи `Ctrl + G` к ячейке `TX5000`
- Добавил в нее текст
- Удалил его

Теперь `Excel` при нажатии `Ctrl + end` показывает эту ячейку.

`Решение` этой проблемы **очень простое**:

1. Открываем MVBA (`Alt+F11`)
2. `Ctrl + G`
3. Вписываем это - **ActiveSheet.UsedRange**

**Работает**. `Excel` сбрасывает ячейку на нужную.

**Проблема в том**, что в моем документе это **не работает**.
Работает после того, как я выберу область (пустую), нажму на `Delete Cell`(кнопка, Home -> Cells) и после этого **ActiveSheet.UsedRange** сбрасывает так как надо.

В чем может быть проблема ?

Спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

Ответа пока не нашел сам. Но подобная проблема (usedrange не сбрасывается пока книгу не переоткрыть) возникла где-то около месяца назад или чуть меньше. До этого все было нормально. 2010 Офис. С форматированием это никак не может быть связанно. Т.к. если даже удалить строки и столбцы где были данные все равно usedrange не сбрасывается, но если добавлять строки и столбцы то и usedrange также увеличивается. Подозреваю что это какой то баг офиса после какого-то обновления. Иногда помогает сохранение книги. Но не всегда.

Пока использую костыль. Но он годен только для книг с макросом и там где не отключена обработка событий.
Для книги добавляю макрос

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Sh.UsedRange.Address
End Sub
```

Таким образом принудительно обновляется диапазон usedrange при любых изменениях в ячейках.

Comment: Спасибо за костыль ! Как-нибудь попробую !)

Answer (score 1):

*ActiveSheet.UsedRange* - пользовательский диапазон активного листа - прямоугольная область до нижней правой использованной ячейки. Не обязательно заполненной - ячейка может быть пустой, но отформатированой.

Почему указанный метод не работает у Вас - не скажу... 
Но нужно ли для этого открывать редактор *VBA*? Достаточно сохранить книгу, и пользовательский диапазон переопределится автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ !

К сожалению, после закрытия/сохранения - ничего не происходит =(

Comment: Закрывать не обязательно. Только сохранить изменения.